# Set action for subview inside a table cell (swift)

Tags: swift

When i clicked the subview,it didn't trigger subview's action. But i have selected whole cell. How to fix it?

Here is my code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("idcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let lblTitle : UILabel = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(101) as! UILabel
    lblTitle.text = (deptId[indexPath.row] as? String)! + "     " + (deptDesc[indexPath.row] as? String)!
    var height:CGFloat = 40
    if(indexPath.row == departmentSelectedRow){
        for i in 0...deptProfile.count-1{
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,height,400,30))
            label.targetForAction("sadasdd", withSender: nil)
            height = height+40
            label.text = ("ewrewrewre")
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            cell.addSubview(label)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: do you think that `targetForAction` is adding a callback for you ?

Comment: how  can i add action for label?

Comment: use a button... you also shouldn't add arbitrary subviews in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - when will they get removed...

Comment: i am working with an expanded cell. i don't get why i shouldn't add arbitrary subviews. i will reload cell when i click other cells

Comment: you reload the table, you reuse the cell...

Comment: sorry i don't quite get it. i am new in programming. So what should i improve? do you mean it will cause memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to interact with something inside a cell (rather than select the whole cell) then you should use a button or a gesture recogniser. These are properly interactive elements that you can add a target and action to.

You should also change how you're using cells, specifically:

1. Use custom cell classes, so you can directly reference the cell elements instead of using `viewWithTag` which is bad practice
2. Use multiple different cell classes (and thus identifiers) so you can use actually different cells for selected and unselected rows
3. Don't create and add subviews on the fly, this is what the different cell classes are for

Comment: what is the drawback if i add subview in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: when you reuse the cell the view will still be there as subviews. you can remove them, but it's wasteful to create and destroy them instead of reuse and how do you find the correct ones to remove (so you need to tag them all and search for them). it can work, but it's very messy (bad) code

Comment: My expanded content is dynamic. can i still use cell classes to handle that?

Comment: i didn't pay too much attention to the loop previously, my first thought about it would be to use a different section in the table for each item and then when it's selected you can insert more rows into the table. so you'd still have 2 different cell classes but you'd be dealing with selection in a different way and animating the addition of the detail items onto the table view (instead of adding a big cell) - this approach also makes height management trivial

Comment: So is my approach appropriate?

Comment: i'd change a lot from your code snippet. the most important part for you is the button / gesture, but life in the future will be a lot easier if you also change how you're dealing with subviews / displaying selection...